# Why does GPU rendering of glass look so wrong compared to CPU? Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Why does the GPU (bottom) rendering look so much worse with weird light bands at the bottom, compared to CPU (top) rendering. Is this a driver issue with the GPU?

[image: Glass cube rendered with cycles on CPU]

[image: Glass cube rendered with cycles on GPU]

Comment: What gpu are you using?

Comment: I would suspect you're right, an issue with the driver or the GPU itself. I usually just have performance differences between CPU and GPU, but the finished result always looks the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the way you constructed this example was to move the default cube up by exactly 1 meter via <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, and then make a plane under it.

This means that the bottom face of your cube and the plane are *coplanar*.  The software can't reliably determine which face is in front of the other.  Actually each result is technically incorrect, the CPU result just appears to handle the z-fighting better.

You need to move the cube up by some additional small amount.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer!